# How to get the targets population numbers through marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, audience

What's marketing API can get the predict daily targets population coverage when setting ads audience step.

It like the picture as below:
[predict daily targets population coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnscI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use reachestimate to get the monthly active people on Facebook that match the audience you defined through targeting spec, more details here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/reachestimate/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/

By Cecile Ho